# select (a or b) as c from table;

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to select `A` if `A` column exists else select `B` column?

For a table

```
A    | B
-----|-----
foo  | bar
NULL | bar
foo  | NULL
```

Result would be

```
C
----
foo
bar
foo
```

It seems there's no function supporting this in docs.

Comment: Do you mean [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) or [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)?

Comment: I thought that question was a joke

Comment: @Anton ha, it's kinda embarrassing. I did not find COALESCE...

Comment: @syg What do you mean you didn't find it????  I Googled "Sql Server coalesce".  This is the first one.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql

Comment: @Eric "Coalesce" isn't exactly a ubiquitous function outside of SQL.

Comment: @Eric for people not working with sql for a long time, coalesce is not the word they come up with first. I tried union, or, || kinda stuff.But it's my bad for not falling back to a simple CASE clause, I totally forgot it. o_O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems there's no function supporting this in docs.

Sure there is.

```
SELECT COALESCE(A,B) AS C
FROM aTable

SELECT ISNULL(A,B) AS C
FROM aTable

SELECT CASE WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN A ELSE B END AS C
FROM aTable
```

Note that, in SQL Server, the query optimizer will rewrite `COALESCE()` into a `CASE` expression equivalent to the third example.